# CSS div nowrap not working in IE

Tags: css, html, nowrap

i'm building a fluid navigation in css, using the iscroll js lib. Now everything's smooth in firefox and chrome. The only problem is with ie.

So basically i'm having a fluid div, which i dont want to wrap or break. In ie it breaks.. i'm using the white-space: nowrap css attribute.

compatibility only for ie8+.

the html code:

```
        <div id="nav">
            <ul class="navigation">
                .. many li tags with a tags inside ..
            </ul>
        </div>
```

the css:

```
.navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #576a85;
    border-left: 1px solid #3e506c;
}
```

and

```
.navigation li {
    float: left;
}

.navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-left: 1px solid #576a85;
    border-right: 1px solid #3e506c;
}
```

some screens of the behaviour:

(chrome)

[image: look in chrome]

(ie)

[image: look in ie]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wait – you want a responsive navigation but don't want it to "break" like in the IE screen which looks way more responsive as in the other screenshot for me?

Comment: thats why i'm using iScroll.. i can horizontally scroll the navigation.

Comment: display:inline-block  ??? Just a hint for you : 'inline-block'

Comment: i'm using inline-block.. look at .navigation class .. li tags are float left

Comment: On mobile devices with small window sizes you can zoom into most of the websites and scroll in every direction. It'd be way better if you **wouldn't have to** zoom in to access the navigation.

Comment: you don't have to zoom in ... the navigation is liquid in itself. you can scroll with your finger, while the page stays the same. it's the iScroll JS plugin. I can provide you a techdemo if you want. There's no horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Scrolling content is not responsive webdesign.

Comment: you're kinda misunderstanding.. take a look at cubiq.org. anyway i fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got the problem now.

the li element has to be inline-block instead of float left and the ul whitespace nowrap ... this way it will be rendered fine in ie.